# Iterate through a dictionary and use value to iterate through class C#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

In my c# code, I have an iteration over a `Dictionary` and want to achieve something like so using `Classes`

```
MyModel othermodel = new MyModel();

Dictionary<string, string> mydictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"n1", "Item"},
    {"n2", "Second"},
    {"n3", "Third"},
    {"n4", "Fourth"},
    {"n5", "Fith"},
    {"n6", "Sixth"},
    {"n7", "Seventh"},
    {"n8", "Eighth"},
    {"n9", "Ninth"},
    {"n0", "Tenth"},
    {"n11", "Eleventh"}

};

foreach (var dicitem in mydictionary.ToArray())
{
    foreach (MyModel.NewItem.(mydictionary[dicitem].Value) item in othermodel.(mydictionary[dicitem].Key))
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

So my result would be:

```
first iteration:

foreach (MyModel.NewItem.Item item in othermodel.n1)
{
     ...
}

second iteration:

foreach (MyModel.NewItem.Second item in othermodel.n2)
{
     ...
}

...
```

If there is a way to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Accessing object properties via its names can be done using `Reflection`, doesn't matter where these names come from (dictionary, array, ...)

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit more or give an example?

Comment: sure, I will post the example in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing object properties via its names can be done using Reflection, doesn't matter where these names come from (dictionary, array, ...)


Little example here:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

then to access the `Name` property you do:

```
var me = new Person {Name = "John", Age = 33};

var propertyName = "Name";
var propertyInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperty(propertyName);

var propertyValue = propertyInfo?.GetValue(me) as string;
```

Using the upper code, you create one Propertynfo. 


If you want to read more properties of the same object, it is better to read all PropertyInfo objects at once:

```
var me = new Person {Name = "John", Age = 33};

var propertiesInfo = typeof(Person).GetProperties();

var propertyName = "Name";
var nameProperty = propertiesInfo
    .Single(p => p.Name == propertyName);
var name = nameProperty.GetValue(me) as string;


//faster approach
var age = (int)propertiesInfo
    .Single(p => p.Name == "Age")
    .GetValue(me);
```

Be be aware that in this example, I suppose that the property with specific name exists, so I simply called `Single`. In different situation however, it may require you to check the existence of property before accessing it.